# converting list of ordered pairs to graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {1, 10}, {1, 12}, {1, 16}, {1, 18},
 {1, 22}, {1, 28}, {1, 30}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {2, 11},
 {2, 15}, {2,17}, {2, 21}, {2, 27}, {2, 29}, {3, 4}, {3, 8},
 {3, 10}, {3,14}, {3, 16}, {3, 20}, {3, 26}, {3, 28}, {4, 7},
 {4, 9}, {4,13}, {4, 15}, {4, 19}, {4, 25}, {4, 27}, {5, 6},
 {5, 8}, {5,12}, {5, 14}, {5, 18}, {5, 24}, {5, 26}, {5, 32},
 {6, 7}, {6,11}, {6, 13}, {6, 17}, {6, 23}, {6, 25}, {6, 31},
 {7, 10}, {7,12}, {7, 16}, {7, 22}, {7, 24}, {7, 30}, {8, 9},
 {8, 11}, {8,15}, {8, 21}, {8, 23}, {8, 29}, {9, 10}, {9, 14},
 {9, 20}, {9,22}, {9, 28}, {9, 32}, {10, 13}, {10, 19}, {10, 21},
 {10, 27}, {10,31}, {11, 12}, {11, 18}, {11, 20}, {11, 26}, {11, 30},
 {11, 32}, {12, 17}, {12, 19}, {12, 25}, {12, 29}, {12, 31}, {13, 16},
 {13, 18}, {13, 24}, {13, 28}, {13, 30}, {14, 15}, {14, 17}, {14, 23},
 {14, 27}, {14, 29}, {15, 16}, {15, 22}, {15, 26}, {15, 28}, {15, 32},
 {16, 21}, {16, 25}, {16, 27}, {16, 31}, {17, 20}, {17, 24}, {17, 26},
 {17, 30}, {18, 19}, {18, 23}, {18, 25}, {18, 29}, {19, 22}, {19, 24},
 {19, 28}, {20, 21}, {20, 23}, {20, 27}, {21, 22}, {21, 26}, {21, 32},
 {22, 25}, {22, 31}, {23, 24}, {23, 30}, {24, 29}, {25, 28}, {26, 27},
 {27, 32}, {28, 31}, {29, 30}, {29, 32}, {30, 31}}
```

I would like to create a graph using this data set to describe the edges. How can I create a graph in mathematica using this data set. I will need to find a hamiltonian path after I create the graph. if you have any ideas about finding the hamiltonian path then please include that in your answer.

Answer (score 8):

First a shorter way to get your list of pairs:

```
list = Select[PrimeQ @* Total] @ Subsets[Range @ 32, {2}]
```

Then, you can use `FindHamiltonianPath` on `list` directly without any  additional processing:

```
FindHamiltonianPath @ list
```

> ```
>  {29, 32, 15, 4, 3, 8, 23, 30, 11, 20, 21, 2, 9, 22, 31, 28, 13, 18,
>   19, 24, 17, 26, 27, 16, 1, 10, 7, 12, 25, 6, 5, 14}
> ```

You can use also  `Graph` and `FindHamiltonianCycle` on `list` directly:

```
Graph @ list
```

[image]

```
FindHamiltonianCycle @ list
```

[image]

```
{EdgeList[Graph[list]] === EdgeList[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ list]],
 Sort @ VertexList[Graph[list]] == 
   Sort @ VertexList[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ list]]
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[list, PathGraph @ FindHamiltonianPath @ list,
   GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled"]
```

[image]

**Note:**  As far as I know, this usage does not appear in documentation. It seems to work if the list `pairs` contains only positive integers. Each pair `{a, b}` is treated as an undirected edge between `a` and `b`. The vertex list is taken to be the list of integers from `1` to `Max@ pairs`; that is, numbers in `Range[Max @ pairs]` that do not appear in `pairs` are treated as isolated vertices.

```
SeedRandom[1]
pairs = RandomInteger[{5, 10}, {4, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{9, 7}, {9, 5}, {6, 5}, {5, 7}}
> ```

```
Graph[pairs, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 1]
```

[image]

```
Graph[pairs, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

```
Through[{VertexList, EdgeList}@Graph[pairs]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
>  {9 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
>   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7}}
> ```

The functions

- `EdgeList`,
- `VertexList`
- `ConnectedComponents`
- `ConnectedGraphComponents`
- `WeaklyConnectedComponents`
- `WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents`
- `VertexComponent`
- `VertexInComponent`
- `VertexOutComponent`
- `KCoreComponents`
- `FindGraphCommunities`
- `FindCycle`
- `FindKClan`
- `FindKClub`
- `FindKClique`
- `HighlightGraph`

also have this undocumented *feature*:

```
EdgeList[pairs]
```

> ```
>   {9 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 5,
>    6 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7}
> ```

```
VertexList[pairs]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
> ```

```
ConnectedComponents[pairs]
```

> ```
>  {{5, 9, 6, 7}, {8}, {4}, {3}, {2}, {1}}
> ```

This works in both version 12.2.0 (Wolfram Cloud):

```
  $Version
```

> ```
>  "12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 16, 2020)"
> ```

and  in version 11.3.0 (Windows 10 64-bit)

```
  $Version
```

> ```
>  "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are interested in `DirectedEdges` between the pairs, something like this will work:

```
Graph[ DirectedEdge@@@list ]
```

(where `list` is a variable storing your list of pairs above)

Unfortunately, this is not a Hamiltonian graph:

```
HamiltonianGraphQ[%] (*False*)
```

However, the *undirected* version *does* contain a Hamiltonian cycle:

```
FindHamiltonianCycle @ Graph[ UndirectedEdge@@@list] (*list of results showing the cycle*)
```

As noted in a subsequent answer, by default `Graph` interprets lists of pairs as a set of undirected edge instructions, so this is equivalent to:

```
FindHamiltonianCycle @ Graph[list]
```

Comment: Your first piece of code can be simplified to: ``Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ list]``

Comment: Indeed! My resolution for 2021 is to overcome my fear of the `@@@` operator :-) Modified to account for this.

Comment: I describe is as 'applying it to a bunch' (mapping of an apply), which made me understand and memorize it years ago…

Answer (score 3):

after I posted this question I found the answer on the wolfram forums. first I found out how to use a rewriting rule to convert my list of lists into a list of undirected edges. then I used a built in function to find the hamiltonian path. some of these lines are here for debugging after Sort and DeleteDuplicates.

```
a = Flatten[
  Table[If[PrimeQ[x + y], {x, y}, ## &[]], {y, 32}, {x, 32}], 1]
b = Map[Sort, a, 1]
c = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[b]]
d = Table[
  If[c[[x]][[1]] != c[[x]][[2]], c[[x]], ## &[]], {x, Length[c]}]
Length[a]
Length[c]
Length[d]
e = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ d]
FindHamiltonianCycle[e]
```

this can be reduced to a one liner with the knowledge that the only even prime number is 1+1 and the lexicographical ordering of the set will have {1,1} first. therefore we drop the first element.

```
FindHamiltonianCycle[
 Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Drop[DeleteDuplicates[
     Sort[Map[Sort, 
       Flatten[Table[
         If[PrimeQ[x + y], {x, y}, ## &[]], {y, 32}, {x, 32}], 1], 
       1]]], 1]]]
```