# Union of list with logical rules for combination

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an list that I would like to reduce according to rules for combination. Examples of the input list (this will be a list of pairs and may be several hundred elements long) and the output I'm looking for with some function f are:

```
f[{{1,4},{1,6}}]
-> {{1,4,6}}
```

The two input lists both contain 1 and are combined. Or

```
f[{{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}}]
-> {{1,4,6},{2,3}}
```

As in the first but {2,3} has no common elements with the others and remains separate.
One way of doing this is with a repeated rule:

```
{{1, 4},{1,6}, {2, 3}} //. {head___, {x_, y_}, mid___, {x_, z_} | {z_, x_} | {y_, z_} | {z_, y_}, tail___} -> {head, {x, y, z}, mid, tail}
-> {{1,4,6},{2,3}}
```

This produces the correct output but has a problem that some other inputs makes clear - the last {4,6} term should have been combined with {1,4,6} and disappear:

```
{{1, 4},{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}//. {head___, {x_, y_}, mid___, {x_, z_} | {z_, x_} | {y_, z_} | {z_, y_}, tail___} -> {head, {x, y, z}, mid, tail}
-> {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}
```

The correct output should be:

```
{{1,4,6},{2,3}}
```

Or

```
{{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}//. {head___, {x_, y_}, mid___, {x_, z_} | {z_, x_} | {y_, z_} | {z_, y_}, tail___} -> {head, {x, y, z}, mid, tail}
-> {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}
```

The correct output should be:

```
{{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}
```

The repeated rule above builds longer lists than pairs (there are then not matched in subsequent iterations) but I haven't found a way of writing a pattern to deal with it (so maybe rule replacement isn't the way to go here), I've tried a couple of other approaches of a more functional nature but seem to be missing something.
Any suggestions?

Comment: So, are you familiar with `Union[]` and `Intersection[]`?

Comment: @J.M. yes, of course, Union[{1,4},{1,6}] yields {1,4,6} but this isn't all there is to it, it would need to be selectively applied and some form of recursion is needed I think. I don't immediately see how Intersection would help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[sep: List[__List]]:= Union @@@ Gather[
    sep, 
    IntersectingQ
]
```

```
f@{{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}
(* {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}} *)
```

```
f@{{1, 4},{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}
(* {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}} *)
```

Alternatively, use pattern:

```
{{1,4},{1,6},{2,3},{4,6}} //. {
    {OrderlessPatternSequence[x1: {__}, x2: {__}, y___]}
    :> {Union[x1, x2], y}/;IntersectingQ[x1, x2]
}
(* {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chromo Runge the Gather method is very elegant and I didn't know the OrderlessPatternSequence function until now

Answer (score 4):

#### KCoreComponents

The function [`KCoreComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KCoreComponents.html) with `1` as the second argument gives the desired result:

```
ClearAll[f1]

f1 = KCoreComponents[#, 1] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f1  @ {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}}
> ```

```
f1  @ {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}}
> ```

```
f1 @ {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}}
> ```

#### ConnectedComponents

Alternatively, you can use [`ConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) and delete singleton elements:

```
ClearAll[f2]

f2 = DeleteCases[{_}] @* ConnectedComponents
```

***Examples:***

```
f2 @ {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}}
> ```

```
f2 @ {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3}}
> ```

```
f2 @ {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}}
> ```

***For fun:***

```
pairs = {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}};

HighlightGraph[pairs, 
  Subgraph[pairs, #] & /@ KCoreComponents[pairs, 1], 
  GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled"]
```

[image]

**Note:** The fact that `KCoreComponents`, `ConnectedComponents`, `Graph` and `HighlightGraph` (as well as many other graph-related functions) accept a list of pairs as the first argument is not documented. The pairs are interpreted as undirected edges. (See also: [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237938/125).)

Comment: Thanks @kglr I keep getting surprised by what can be done with graph functionality once a problem has been formulated in a way that exploits it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to join all sub lists that have some elements in common und delete duplicates. This can be achieved by e.g.:

```
{{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 
   5}} //. {y1___, x1:{__}, y2___, x2:{__}, y3___} /; 
   Intersection[x1, x2] != {} :> {y1, Union[x1, x2], y2, y3}

(*{{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}*)
```