# Graph with non-integer vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Why the following works only with integers and if other names of vertices are used `UndirectedEdge` is needed?

```
{Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}], Graph[{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}}], 
  Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}}]} // Row
```

---

[image]

Comment: This is not a documented syntax. If you use it, you are risking that your code will break in the future. A bit of experimentation does reveal that with this syntax one must use vertex indices, not names.

Comment: related Q/As: [converting list of ordered pairs to graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237938/125) and [Union of list with logical rules for combination](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240264/125)